# Создание нового пользователя в Ubuntu 16 server

Tags: ubuntu

У меня есть установленный ubuntu - сервер. Я захожу в него под `root`, ввожу команду `useradd user`, но папки `/home/user` не появляется как desktop версии. Почему ? Как создать полноценного пользователя ?

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте добавить пользователя через `adduser user`.

Answer (score 2):

Ознакомьтесь с командой `man useradd`

Добавить нового пользователя и указать домашнюю папку

```
sudo useradd -d /home/testuser -m testuser
```

Задать пароль пользователю

```
sudo passwd testuser
```

Answer (score 1):

> Почему ?

Потому что по-умолчанию домашний каталог не создаётся.

> Как создать полноценного пользователя ?

Используйте параметр -m:

`useradd -m user`